# How can I view the path from the 'google drive api' file list

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I have followed https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list, successful! I got it all. But not my 'drive'. I received a warning 'You need to be granted access here. So what should I do to fix the above error?

I created a new project, Service account keys and OAuth 2.0 client IDs. but it's bad it doesn't properly link to my 'google drive' account

**This is my whole code**

```
<?php
    session_start ();

    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxx@phim-240702.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'phim-240702-a98343eb742a.p12';

    function buildService(){
      global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;
      $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
      $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
        $key);

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setApplicationName("googletest5");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("b2016fa55e916faf35337ccb1db830ecdb590cc3");
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_DriveService($client);
    }

    /**
     * Insert new file.
     *
     * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
     * @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
     * @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
     * @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
     * @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
     * @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
     * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is
     *     returned if an API error occurred.
     */
    function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
      $file = new Google_DriveFile();
      $file->setTitle($title);
      $file->setDescription($description);
      $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

      // Set the parent folder.
      if ($parentId != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($parentId);
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
      }

      try {
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);

        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
          'data' => $data,
          'mimeType' => '$mimeType',
        ));

        return $createdFile;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of File resources.
     *
     * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
     * @return Array List of Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile resources.
     */
    function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
      $result = array();
      $pageToken = NULL;

      do {
        try {
      $parameters = array(
        'maxResults' => '100'
        );
          if ($pageToken) {
            $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
          }
          $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

          $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
          $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
          $pageToken = NULL;
        }
      } while ($pageToken);
      return $result;
    try {

      $root_id = null;
      $service = buildService();
       print_r(retrieveAllFiles($service));
      }catch (Exception $e) {
         print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: I just started to learn about 'google drive api'. I look forward to receiving everyone's suggestions

Answer (score 0):

What you need to remember is that a Service account is not you. A service account is a dummy user. It has its own google drive account. when you upload the files to the service accounts drive account they are only accessible by that account as it is the owner of it.

## Share a drive

If you want it to be able to access files on your personal drive account you will need to grant it access to them by sharing them with the service accounts email address.  This is how service accounts are pre approved.

## getting path

As for getting the path of a file there is no easy way to do that you will need to step your way though it by getting the file, then getting its parent, followed by getting any more parents until you hit the top and build it up that way.

Comment: Your comment helped me understand the problem. Thanks so much for that.

Comment: I fixed the above error. But I want to take advantage of the 'downloadUrl' link to download the file. But I get a warning "This page is not working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.HTTP ERROR 401 " . It is wasteful to not be able to use it. Can you explain help me this problem? thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to open that as a new question and accept this one as that is unrelated to the first question.  However downloadurl is only going to work for a user that actually has access to the file, you need to grant the user permissions to the file..   You can try setting the file to public though then everyone should have access to download it.